# which polynomials form a basis for $P_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S=(1+5x,1-4x^2)$. Which of the following polynomials could be added to the set $S$ to form a basis for $P_2$?

i. $2+5x-5x^2$

ii. $6+5x-21x^2$

iii. $6+20x-8x^2$

So, I proceeded to add them together and obtained:

$3+10x-5x^2,3+5x-9x^2$

$7+10x-21x^2,7+5x-25x^2$

$7+25x-8x^2,7+20x-12x^2$

I then put the above into a coefficient matrix and put the matrices into reduced row echelon form. Every single one was linearly independent which means they form a basis $P_2$

Clearly I have done something wrong as my answer "all of them" was incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: If I'm getting you right, you put $4$ vectors in the co-efficient matrix at once? Note that $4$ vectors in a $3$ dimensional vector space $(\mathbb P_2)$ will always be linearly dependent. Just put the two basis vectors along with $(i),(ii)$ or $(iii)$ with only $3$ vectors in the coefficient matrix at a time.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

With reference to the basis $\{1,x,x^2\}$ let consider the matrix for the five vectors

- $(1,5,0)$
- $(1,0,-4)$
- $(2,5,-5)$
- $(6,5,-21)$
- $(6,20,-8)$

and perform the RREF keeping 2 pivots for the first 2 vectors.

As an alternative, calculate the determinant for the matrices with the first two vectors and each one of the other three vectors in order to check for which one we have $\det A \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The new polynomial should be independent from the two others we already have. (iii) is not a candidate for sure since $$6+20x-8x^2=4(1+5x)+2(1-4x^2)$$while (i) and (ii) can complete the basis since they are independent.